# Access a component variable from another

Tags: angular

I'm trying to integrate sidenav to my application, but it required the sidenav code to be in the main app.component page while actually I need the sidenav only in one component.

I have a variable called **combos**. if `combos.length >=1`, I show the sidenav.

That's the code I placed in my app.component.html:

```
    <md-sidenav-layout>
      <md-sidenav #IVCombos mode="side" *ngIf="result?.combos?.length >=1">
MY SIDENAV
      </md-sidenav>

    <!-- Routed views go here -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </md-sidenav-layout>
```

As you can see, the content is wrapped within the sidenav. One the user place some data on my inputs on one of my router components, the `combos` variable changes.

Since this variable is instance of a router component and not in my app.component.ts as in my HTML, the sidenav is not shown.

**My question is:**

What would be the best way to access my component `combos` variable from my app.component.ts?

Is it neccessary to create a service for one variable in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best choice will be use shared service. Also it is possible to use store in this kind of situations, but it is not necessary in your case.

**Shared Service (in Shared Module):**

Just store your data as service class *property*.

**Disadvantages:**

- In Angular 2, services could be global or module scoped. What does it mean? That if you add your service into *global* module providers array and by mistake - also as your *feature* module provider, angular 2 will create **two** instances of your service, so one of them - will have empty data. Similar problem you can find there - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#q-why-it-is-bad

**Ngrx store (like Redux):**

You could use ngrx store concept - https://github.com/ngrx/store.

**Advantages:**

- You could *subscribe* your store in all pieces of application, in each component, so you can properly react on every data change,
- Data in store will be *immutable* - to change anything, you have to dispatch an action, which invokes pure reducer function, so it is not possible to modify any user data by accident.

Comment: So-called 'disadvantages' are fundamental concepts of A2 hierarchical injectors, don't blame a gun for shooting in one's foot - Ngrx store could be blamed for being used as a 'global' as well.  It is a matter of religious preferences, I don't think that either one of them fits the navigation case better than another. A shared service can be event emitter to be subscribed, too.

Comment: In 'disadvantages' section, I am trying to describe a problem. I am not saying that "In Angular 2, services could be global or module scoped" is disadvantage.